# Generating a .Jar file in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, applet

I've made a Java Applet but when I made the project I didnt check the box that says "Create main class".
When I execute the ".jar" file generated by Netbeans it doesn't run because the ".jar" file doesn't know who the main class is. 
I've tried editing the "manifest.mf" before building the ".jar" file but it doesn't solve the problem.
What else can I do? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you made a java applet it wont run as a standalone file (double clicking the Jar file). Applets are meant to run in a browser as an embedded element. I think what you are looking for is a JFrame.

Comment: Applets do not have to have `main` method and (if they do) do not use it as entry point anyway. They use `init'` when run as Applets (see https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html#runanddebug).

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm trying to run it on a webpage but when using the following html code it generates an error which says it can't access the main class.
<APPLET CODE="Japplet.Main.class" archive="GeneticaVaq.jar"  WIDTH="700" HEIGHT="500"> </APPLET>
Thats why I wanted the ".jar" file itself to know the main class.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For deploying Java ***desktop*** apps., the best option is usually to link the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.